# Making columns to be dynamic by adding checkboxe in Shiny

Tags: javascript, html, r, checkbox, shiny

I've been trying to add a row (basically a row of check boxes) on my data table, so that users will be able to decide which column they like to keep/delete. And here is what my Shiny App looks like so far. Anyone who knows any hints please help!

Any help would be appreciated!

```
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(disable = T),
                dashboardSidebar(disable = T),
                dashboardBody(uiOutput("MainBody")))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  vals <- reactiveValues()
  vals$data <- data.table(vals$Data<-data.table(
           Brands=paste0("Brand",1:10),
           Forecasted_Growth=sample(1:20,10),
           Last_Year_Purchase=round(rnorm(10,1000,1000)^2),
           Contact=paste0("Brand",1:10,"@email.com")
 ))

      output$MainBody <- renderUI({
        fluidPage(
          box(width = 12,
          h3(strong("Template"), align = "center"),
          hr(),
          column(6, offset = 6, 
                 actionButton(inputId = "Del_Col", label = "Delete Select Column"))),
      column(12, dataTableOutput("MainTable")),
      tags$script()
    )
  })
```

Comment: I think it would be good if you go through all the tutorials on shiny website, as you have fundamental mistakes within your code https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for your help Pork Chop~ I take the advice!

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Pork Chop that you should rethink your layout. I couldn't get my head around it so I reworked it into a minimal fluidpage.

The code below should get you close. It renders buttons (you could make these checkboxes though) directly into the table using a helper function [described here.](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/178) The code below uses these buttons to subset and update the dataframe which I term `reactiveTable`. Here's the functionality:

[image]

Good luck!

```
library(data.table)
library(DT)

## Nice helper function to make the buttons from:
## https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/178
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
  }
  inputs
}

## Basic UI with a reset button
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    h1('Table Subsetter'),
    actionButton('reset', 'Reset!'),
    DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  #This is the table you provided in your question
  tableA <- data.table(
    Brands=paste0("Brand",1:10),
    Forecasted_Growth=sample(1:20,10),
    Last_Year_Purchase=round(rnorm(10,1000,1000)^2),
    Contact=paste0("Brand",1:10,"@email.com")
  )

  #make a reactive value for the table and columns to delete
  reactiveTable <- reactiveValues(tab=tableA)
  columnToDelete <- reactiveValues(col=NULL)

  #Logic to make the buttons, reruns everytime the table is updated
  tableOut <- reactive({
    buttons <- shinyInput(actionButton, length(reactiveTable$tab[1,]), 'button_', label = "Delete!", onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\",  this.id)' )
    buttons <- t(as.data.frame(buttons, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
    colnames(buttons) = colnames(reactiveTable$tab)
    rbind(buttons, reactiveTable$tab)
  })

  #reset button replaces the table
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    reactiveTable$tab <- tableA
  })

  #listener to for the delete button 
  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    columnToDelete$col <-as.numeric(strsplit(input$select_button, "_")[[1]][2])
      reactiveTable$tab <- subset( reactiveTable$tab, select = -columnToDelete$col )
  })

  #output the table with DT. use escape=F so it renders the html
  output$mytable <- DT::renderDataTable({
                      tableOut()
                      },server = FALSE, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none')

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That is almost what I want. You and Pork Chop are right, reading through the tutorial will help.

Comment: Hey, I tried the code, but seems like when I jumps to page 2, the delete button doesn't appear on it. Do you have any further ideas on this?

Comment: The button is embedded in row 1 so thats why it goes away. You could try to put it into the header to keep it!